# What is a geometric relation?

Tags: relations

> We will call a relation geometric if $∀x, y, z(xRy ∧ xRz → yRz)$
>
> Prove that if a relation is geometric and reflexive, then it is also
> symmetric.

I'm trying to solve this problem but I don't understand the question. I've heard of Reflexive, Symmetric, Transitive, and equivalence relation, but not geometric?

Comment: But you have the definition there...

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that $xRy$ implies $yRx$.
So suppose that $xRy$;
since $R$ is reflexive, you have that $xRx$.
So, just take $z=x$ in the definition and obtain $yRx$.